# Getting Wordpress Meta Box values to appear on my posts?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post, meta

I'm a newbie Wordpress developer & I can't figure out how to get the options chosen in my Custom Meta Boxes to populate on my posts. For example, this is how my admin panel looks when creating new posts:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RGz8.jpg

To give you an example of my code for this section that is in my meta.php file... It's:

```
    //POST META BOXES
        'post'=> array(

            array(
                'name' => 'Home Type',
                'id' => PEXETO_META_PREFIX.'text',
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => array( array( 'name'=>'1', 'id'=>'1' ),
                    array( 'name'=>'2', 'id'=>'2' ),
                    array( 'name'=>'3', 'id'=>'3' ),
                    array( 'name'=>'4', 'id'=>'4' ),
                    array( 'name'=>'5', 'id'=>'5' ) ),
                'desc' => '...'
            ),

            array(
                'name' => 'Listing Status',
                'id' => PEXETO_META_PREFIX.'text',
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => array( array( 'name'=>'1', 'id'=>'1' ),
                    array( 'name'=>'2', 'id'=>'2' ),
                    array( 'name'=>'3', 'id'=>'3' ) ),
                'desc' => '...'
            ),

            array(
                'name' => 'Lot Size',
                'id' => PEXETO_META_PREFIX.'text',
                'type' => 'text',
                'desc' => '...'
            ),
```

What I'm trying to do is set it up so that each meta box will generate a two column row in my actual post. The left side would show the title of the box, and the right side would show the answer given by the user. An example of this is below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/suJTq.jpg

Any help with this one would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm unsure as to where I should start... every tutorial on the web only helps me to create the actual meta boxes. I can't find anything that helps me code them into my pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Then something like this to echo those metas out in a table:

```
$metas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
echo '<table>';
foreach( $metas as $key => $meta ) {
    printf('<tr><th>%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>',
    $key, $meta[0] );
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Looks like it's starting to get somewhere! Thanks for this. My confusion now is that instead of seeing my meta data for this post type (As I believe I wrote in my code above) - I see some values that are completely unrelated to what I wrote? Screenshot here -> http://imgur.com/rEzFIZX

Comment: It gets all of a post's meta, that stuff included. You'll probably want to add some conditions (if/else statements) to filter the output, or add more descriptive keys. This was just a bare-bones example on how to fetch and display the metas :)